# Tensorflow Keras error when I tried to load and use a pre-trained model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

As mentioned I wanna use a pre-trained model but only as a feature extractor. My thought is to build a new model and load weights to it:

```
    model = get_tiny_darknet_model() #get the structure of the model
    transfer_layer = model.get_layer('global_average_pooling2d')
    feature_extractor = Model(inputs=model.input,
                              outputs=transfer_layer.output)
    feature_extractor.load_weights('checkpoints\\checkpoint.h5', by_name=True)
```

But when I tried to use this feature extractor to make predictions, an error occurs.

```
train_data = raw_preprocess(train_data) #use a ImageDataGenerator to preprocess the data
train_samples = feature_extractor.predict(train_data)
```

And after I run this code, the following error occurs:

```
2020-06-12 16:22:09.409465: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-12 16:22:10.830022: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-06-12 16:22:10.830519: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-06-12 16:22:10.830794: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Studium/Thesis/loss_test.py", line 35, in <module>
    test_mmd()
  File "E:/Studium/Thesis/loss_test.py", line 24, in test_mmd
    c_train_samples = feature_extractor.predict(train_data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 909, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 648, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 265, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 535, in predict_on_batch
    return model.predict_on_batch(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1157, in predict_on_batch
    outputs = self.predict_function(inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3740, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1081, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1121, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node conv2d/Conv2D (defined at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\TF_2G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_2495]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph


Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, if I just load the model and use it directly like:

```
model = load_model('checkpoints\\checkpoint.h5')
train_data = raw_preprocess(train_data)
pred =  model.predict(train_data)
```

Then everything will work just fine and no error will occur.
What's possibly the reason for that? How can I solve this problem?
I just checked the information while running and saw something like a warning:

```
2020-06-12 21:18:36.913051: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
```

And I try to reload the original model and a new problem occurs:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
```

This is a new problem that I've never seen before when loading a model. What could cause the problem and how to solve this? I've tried to build a new conda environment but it doesn't help.

Comment: Hie @PokeLu are you using TensorFlow 2.0??

Comment: @Rishabh Jain  Yep.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iPython (Spyder or Jupyter), this pretty frequently comes up in the event that you forgot to properly close an old kernel using tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'm using neither of them in Pycharm. The strange thing is that if I run   model.predict(train_data)  before   feature_extractor.predict(train_data) then it works fine again.

Comment: @PokeLu maybe just a reinstall or make a new conda environment to test out

Comment: I rebuild a new conda environment but the same happened. And I think there is a warning I haven't seen before: Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2   @Andrew H

Comment: @PokeLu That's a new one for me. In the "old days," 3-4 years ago, installing tensorflow was a constant battle. Seems that might still be going some for your setup, but generally I find the anaconda install goes very smooth. You could try a pip install as well, might as well.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. What a battle it is!